# regex removes all characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert a Javascript I wrote some time ago into PHP.
This script replaces special characters like é with e, ú with u, and so forth.

That first part works. However, at the end I have a line that checks if now all characters were removed. This last part does not work.

Here it is:

```
if ($str != preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z \-]+/g","",$str)) {
     echo "error: ".$str." - ".preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z \-]+/g","",$str);
}
```

Now as I said, if I let the script run with `$str = "Péter";` for example, then $str will be "Peter" before it reaches this point.
But in any case, I get this output:

```
error: Peter -
```

I wonder how this can be, because I use the same regex as in my Javascript and there it works.

Comment: How is it converting `é` to `e` ? Does it really go from `Péter` to `Peter` ?

Comment: Since `preg_replace()` is obviously returning an empty string, `'Peter' != ''` would be true, in which case the error will be echo'd

Comment: @MichaelWheeler Yes, that's not the question. The question is WHY does it return empty, and I just got the answer. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not recognize the `/g` modifier at all, which causes `preg_replace` to return `null` and trigger a warning (you can verify this with `var_dump` on the result) because of the invalid pattern.

Remove `/g` and the code works as expected. `preg_replace` already replaces all occurrences of the pattern, so it will still work the same as the JavaScript version.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a problem. If the script is to compare the following: if ("Peter != preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z \-]+/g","","Peter") {}, how can it be that it removes all characters? Do you mean "e" is not the same as "e" or "P" is not considered the same as "P"? Please explain

Comment: @koljanep: Sorry, that was a mistake -- I didn't quite stop to think. The problem is that PHP does not recognize the `/g` modifier (it also doesn't need it).